# How do I flatten a java map to a list such that the list alternates keys and values?

Tags: java, reduce, flatten

How do I flatten a java map to a list such that the list contains {k1,v1,k2,v2,...} using java streams?

Answer (score 2):

Create a stream from each entry of the map; then use `flatMap` to flatten these substreams into a stream; and collect like usual:

```
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: You missed one `)` for  closing `flatMap`, +1 anyway.